# scroll all CollectionViewCell inside all tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am creating a custom Tableviewcell having CollectionView inside it. When scrolling a CollectionView inside a tableview cell , I want the cells in other CollectionViews to get automatically scrolled.

How can I implement this ?
 [the "parameters" and "unit" are UILabels inside Tableview cell, the "labels" are the uiLabels of "Collectioniew" inside UITableviewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBMTg.png)

Comment: Please share your code for better explanation.

Comment: use `scrollViewDidScroll` to detect scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Both `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` are sub-classes of `UIScrollView` so you can do one of these things to manipulate the scroll:

- set `contentOffset` on them or,
- use `func scrollToItem(at: IndexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition, animated: Bool)`

What you do depends on how you wish your UI to work.

Assuming each tableview cell contains a collection the basic technique will be:

1. When inner collection is scrolled by the user , you can detect this with the `UIScrollViewDelegate` delegate method `func scrollViewDidScroll(UIScrollView)`. There [are other](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate)  `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods that will help here too.
2. Apply the detected change in content offset/position to all other collections in (visible) tableview cells.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate it with example?